# Most idiomatic way to sort, and then subsort nested table in lua?

Tags: sorting, lua

I have a table of nine {x,y} points, and I'd like to sort it first by y, then by x.  Probably best explained by my current code:

```
coords = {{135, 487}, {135, 298}, {334, 308}, {334, 485}, {554, 301}, {555, 400}, {136, 97}, {334, 98}, {552, 107}}

table.sort(coords, function(a, b) return b[2] > a[2] end)
t1 = {}
table.insert(t1, coords[1])
table.insert(t1, coords[2])
table.insert(t1, coords[3])
t2 = {}
table.insert(t2, coords[4])
table.insert(t2, coords[5])
table.insert(t2, coords[6])
t3 = {}
table.insert(t3, coords[7])
table.insert(t3, coords[8])
table.insert(t3, coords[9])
table.sort(t1, function(a, b) return b[1] > a[1] end)
table.sort(t2, function(a, b) return b[1] > a[1] end)
table.sort(t3, function(a, b) return b[1] > a[1] end)
coords[1] = t1[1]
coords[2] = t1[2]
coords[3] = t1[3]
coords[4] = t2[1]
coords[5] = t2[2]
coords[6] = t2[3]
coords[7] = t3[1]
coords[8] = t3[2]
coords[9] = t3[3]

for i, t in ipairs(coords) do
    print ("X: " .. t[1] .. " Y: " .. t[2])
end
```

The program produces the desired output, which is this:

```
X: 136 Y: 97
X: 334 Y: 98
X: 552 Y: 107
X: 135 Y: 298
X: 334 Y: 308
X: 554 Y: 301
X: 135 Y: 487
X: 334 Y: 485
X: 555 Y: 400
```

So the y coordinates are grouped in threes, and within those groups of three the points are sorted by x.  The problem is I can't do a normal "sort by y, if y's are equal sort by x" because the y's aren't equal, they're just "grouped."  I'm very new to Lua, so I was wondering if there was a more idiomatic or graceful way of accomplishing this rather than what I'm currently doing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
table.sort(coords, function(a,b) return a[2]<b[2] end)
for i, coord in ipairs(coords) do
  coord.g = math.floor((i-1)/3)  -- group no
end
table.sort(coords, function(a,b) return a.g<b.g or a.g==b.g and a[1]<b[1] end)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no more idiomatic or straightforward method to create your special order.
Your code can only be trimmed and generified, like this:

```
coords = {{135, 487}, {135, 298}, {334, 308}, {334, 485}, {554, 301}, {555, 400}, {136, 97}, {334, 98}, {552, 107}}

table.sort(coords, function(a, b) return b[2] > a[2] end)
for i = 1, #coords, 3 do
    local t = {coords[i], coords[i+1], coords[i+2]}
    table.sort(t, function(a, b) return b[1] > a[1] end)
    coords[i], coords[i+1], coords[i+2] = t[1], t[2], t[3]
end

for i, t in ipairs(coords) do
    print ("X: " .. t[1] .. " Y: " .. t[2])
end
```